# Проблема с плагином jQUI selectmenu

Tags: html, jquery

Такая ситуация: если применить плагин к выпадающему списку - selectmenu(), то переключатели начинают работать некорректно. Например если выбрать "Закрыть" то список больше не откроется. Таких проблем нет если отключить selectmenu().

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        
    $(':radio').click(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="nedzen"){ 
            $('select').prop('disabled',true);
        }
        else
            $('select').prop('disabled',false);
    });
    
    $('select').selectmenu();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<select name="theme" class="op1">
     <option value="ox" >Выбор 1</option>
     <option value="light">Выбор 2</option>
     <option value="dark">Выбор 3</option>
</select>

<input name="dz"  id="dzen" type="radio" value="dzen">
<label for="dzen" >Открыть</label>
<input name="dz" id="nedzen" type="radio" value="nedzen">
<label for="nedzen">Закрыть</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызов `$('select').selectmenu();` прячет родной элемент `select` и создает новые элементы. Используйте:

```
$("select").selectmenu("disable");

$("select").selectmenu("enable");
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-disable

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        
    $(':radio').click(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="nedzen"){ 
            $('select').selectmenu('disable');
        }
        else
            $('select').selectmenu('enable');
    });
    
    $('select').selectmenu();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<select name="theme" class="op1">
     <option value="ox" >Выбор 1</option>
     <option value="light">Выбор 2</option>
     <option value="dark">Выбор 3</option>
</select>

<input name="dz"  id="dzen" type="radio" value="dzen">
<label for="dzen" >Открыть</label>
<input name="dz" id="nedzen" type="radio" value="nedzen">
<label for="nedzen">Закрыть</label>
```